# Editing httpd.conf to use apache server on mac

Tags: php, apache, macos, chmod

I have tried to uncomment the line in this file to enable php however when i open in nano oe any text editor i connot save i have tried sudo, chmod and nothing works i even tried this type of chmod that was mentioned in a tutorial ...

```
sudo chmod 755 httpd.conf
```

but still says that i have not the permission to alter the file. has anyone succeded what i am trying to achieve.

this is the error i get when editing it in nano

```
[error writing httpd.conf: permission denied]
```

Comment: Are you the owner of the file? Then that is strange. If not, are you in the group that owns the file? When yes , then alter the permissions to 775. If not then become a member of the owning group and change the permissions that way or become the owner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried simply using `sudo nano httpd.conf` rather than trying to chmod it?